# Proper way to import and run the compiled file of Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a compile file (xxx.pyc) that was generated with a code: `py_compile.compile(path+'xxx.py')`. I imported to run the compile file and found no problem at the same folder.
If I moved the compile file to a different folder and tried to import and run the compile in the new folder, ModuleNotFoundError of "No module named 'xxx'" pops up.
Please help me find the mistakes I made and the solution. Thank you

Comment: Are you using cython? Or is just a regular python file? If it is regular just run it with your python3 binary if on Linux or exe on windows.

Comment: I am using a regular Python on Windows 10.

Comment: Is the python exe on your environment variable PATH?

Comment: Yes.   Some additions: I just found that if the source code resides in the same folder, it works OK. Is it what is supposed to be?

Comment: So it can work that way, but not it's not supposed to, instead since the python.exe is inside your PATH. You can use either PowerShell instance to run the code via `cd [dir]` to change directory into the directory then run `python [file.py]`. That should work